# How to properly build Nmap solution on windows?

Tags: perl, visual-c++, openssl, visual-studio-2022, nmap

I am trying to build Nmap from source code, and I think I am incorrectly installing/compiling/using OpenSSL, but I'm not sure it is the first time using many of the tools found in the instructions for nmap compilation.

I follow the instructions here: https://nmap.org/book/inst-windows.html#inst-win-source

I follow everything, including the instructions found at https://svn.nmap.org/nmap-mswin32-aux/OpenSSL-upgrade.txt; which is required since the OpenSSL folder that comes with the nmap source distribution does not include some header files from configuring OpenSSL.

I can build every project within the solution up until nsock, in total I get about 3700 errors. For nsock its 435 errors, things like:

"sslctx is not a member of npool"
"ssl_session is not a member of niod"

but also things like "syntex error: missing ; before *"

My directory looks like nmap -> [nmap-7.93, nmap-mswin32-aux]

Pretty sure it has something to do with how I'm installing or building or using OpenSSL, but I follow the instructions https://svn.nmap.org/nmap-mswin32-aux/OpenSSL-upgrade.txt closely and multiple times now.

I'm using MSVC 2022, I have 2019 installed (I'm really not sure which to use, or how to stop perl from using 2022 and use 2019 tools), or if I'm missing something else that is basic.

I did notice perl uses nmake from MSVC2022, and it's mentioned on the nmap site to use 2019. Could this be the problem? How would I get pearl to use MSVC2019 to test it out?

I followed the instructions multiple times, with both openssl sources 1.1.1s and 3.0.7 in MS VS 2019 and 2022. The result is all up 3700 errors about syntax errors and being unable to identify ssl names.

Happy to provide any additional info like perl dump files if anyone can aid me, or the complete list of errors. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Instead of building from source, did you try the [executable self-installer](https://nmap.org/download.html#windows) ?

Comment: I tried to build nmap 7.93 on Windows 11, using Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2022 . When I execute "Build" for the nmap project, I get the following errors: https://imgur.com/a/WwwOEFc

Comment: I forgot to run `svn checkout https://svn.nmap.org/nmap-mswin32-aux` first, I now get these errors instead: https://imgur.com/a/UuF06ys